# C# split math expression in Terms

Tags: c#, regex, string, list, split

I need something that can split an expression like this:

```
string expression = "2e^{x^{2}+2}+x-x^{2}";
```

I want to safe the terms in a List like this:

```
0: 2e^{x^2}+2}
1: +
2: x
3: -
4: x^{2}
```

currently I am splitting like this:

```
var Terms = Regex.Split(PolynomString, @"\s*([-+/*])\s*").Where(n => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(n)).ToList();
```

but this will split my terms also within the exponent what I don't want:

```
0: 2e^{x^{2}
1: +
2: 2}
3: +
4: x
5: -
6:x^{2}
```

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/MathosProject/Mathos-Parser

Comment: "...like this:" is problematic. Readers could suggest how you could split that specific string in the way you want, but that solution might not work on other strings you may wish to split, such as `"2e^{x^{2}+{e^{2}+1}}+x-x^{2}"`. Incidently one normally see parentheses rather braces in such expressions.

Comment: Try `\w+(\^\{(?>[^{}]+|(?<o>{)|(?<-o>}))*})?|[+-]`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this works but this only safes the terms with e^

Comment: Sure, you asked *"something that can split an expression like this"*. If you need more help, explain in detail what you need.

Comment: I need to split exponential terms into a string list splitting after each + or - but I don't want to split when the minus or plus is  within an exponent  check : e^{2+x}. So for example the expression string  "e^{2+x^{2}}+x^{2}-3" should be splitted into an list 0: e^{2+x^{2}}  ; +  ; x^{2}  ; -    ; 3      this didn't work for me with my regex expression from the code above cause it splits every + and -  also when its inside an term in the exponent. I hope you know get my problem sry for the ambiguity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split on matches of the following regular expression.

```
(?=[+-])(?![^{]+})|(?<=[+-])(?![^{]+})
```

with the multiline flag set.

[Demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3d%5b%2b-%5d%29%28%3f!%5b%5e%7b%5d%2b%7d%29%7c%28%3f%3c%3d%5b%2b-%5d%29%28%3f!%5b%5e%7b%5d%2b%7d%29&i=2e%5e%7bx%5e%7b2%7d%2b2%7d%2bx-x%5e%7b2%7d%0d%0a1%2b3-2%2b%7b2*7%2b3%7d%2b4&o=m) (Click on "split list")

Note that all the matches are zero-width locations before and after '-' and '+'.

I have assumed that all braces are balanced and there are no nested  braces.

The .NET regex engine performs the following operations.

```
(?=[+-])    the following char must be '+' or '-'
(?![^{]+})  the current location cannot be followed by 1+ chars 
            other than '}' followed by '}'
|           or
(?<=[+-])   the preceding char must be '+' or '-'         
(?![^{]+})  the current location cannot be followed by 1+ chars
            other than '}' followed by '}'
```

Comment: works but found that for the case 2e^{+2+x+x^{2}}+x-x^{2} splitting doesn't work as expected if I place an exponential term here x^{2} at the end of the e^ Term and they are other terms before

Comment: Ma Lord, I said in my answer that I've assumed there are no nested braces, as in the expression in your comment. I don't know if that's the problem, but I'll have a look in awhile.

Comment: Ma Lord, let's see what happens when the regex engine's pointer is right before the first `"+"` in `"2e^{+2+x+x^{2}}+x-x^{2}"`. The positive lookahead `(?=[+-])` is satisfied. The `[^{]+` in the negative lookahead `(?![^{]+})` matches `"+2+x+x^"`. The following character, `"2"` does not match `}` in the regex, however, so the negative lookahead fails (i.e., is unsuccessful in finding a match), meaning that the first `"+"` is matched. It's only matched, however, because the string contains nested braces...

Comment: That's why I stated in my answer that I assumed that (as in your question) there are no nested braces and the braces are balanced. It is also the reason for my "like this" comment on the question, where I give an example of string with nested braces that is not "like this".